# React Testing Library render leaking between tests

Tags: react-testing-library

I'm currently writing some tests and noticed that the rendered screen is being carried over between tests.

The following 3 tests are being affected:

```js
describe('rolls', () => {
    it('are ordered', async () => {
        render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <RollGroup group={0} abilities={mockAbilities} />
            </Provider>
        );

        await clickAllRollButtons();

        for (const { rolls } of store.getState().rollGroups[0]) {
            for (let i = 0; i < (rolls?.length as number) - 1; ++i) {
                expect((rolls as number[])[i]).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(
                    (rolls as number[])[i + 1]
                );
            }
        }
    });

    it('are between 1 and 6', async () => {
        render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <RollGroup group={0} abilities={mockAbilities} />
            </Provider>
        );

        await clickAllRollButtons();

        for (const roll of store
            .getState()
            .rollGroups[0].reduce(
                (prev: number[], { rolls }) => prev.concat(rolls as number[]),
                [] as number[]
            )) {
            expect(roll).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(1);
            expect(roll).toBeLessThanOrEqual(6);
        }
    });
});

it('removes selected options from options of other dropdowns', async () => {
    render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <RollGroup group={0} abilities={mockAbilities} />
        </Provider>
    );

    await clickAllRollButtons();

    const dropdowns = screen.getAllByLabelText(/Select ability/i);
    const selected = [];

    await userEvent.selectOptions(dropdowns.at(0) as HTMLElement, 'CON');
    selected.push('CON');

    const secondDropdown = dropdowns.at(1) as HTMLSelectElement;
    for (const s of selected) {
        expect(getSelectOptions(secondDropdown)).not.toContain(s);
    }
    await userEvent.selectOptions(secondDropdown, 'STR');
    selected.push('STR');

    const thirdDropdown = dropdowns.at(2) as HTMLSelectElement;
    for (const s of selected) {
        expect(getSelectOptions(thirdDropdown)).not.toContain(s);
    }
    await userEvent.selectOptions(thirdDropdown, 'DEX');
    selected.push('DEX');

    const fourthDropdown = dropdowns.at(3) as HTMLSelectElement;
    for (const s of selected) {
        expect(getSelectOptions(fourthDropdown)).not.toContain(s);
    }
    await userEvent.selectOptions(fourthDropdown, 'INT');
    selected.push('INT');

    const fifthDropDown = dropdowns.at(4) as HTMLSelectElement;
    for (const s of selected) {
        expect(getSelectOptions(fifthDropDown)).not.toContain(s);
    }
    await userEvent.selectOptions(fifthDropDown, 'CHA');
    selected.push('CHA');

    const sixthDropdown = dropdowns.at(5) as HTMLSelectElement;
    for (const s of selected) {
        expect(getSelectOptions(sixthDropdown)).not.toContain(s);
    }
});
```

Also relevant to the issue is the `clickAllRollButtons` function:

```js
const clickAllRollButtons = async () => {
    for (const button of screen.getAllByText(/Roll/i)) {
        await userEvent.click(button);
    }
};
```

When I try running the entire suite of tests, the tests fail with the following error:

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: /Roll/i. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.
```

I looked at the markup returned in the error message and it's the markup I expect to see after all the roll buttons are clicked and there are none left. However, when I run only one of the tests using `it.only`, I get a success.

At first, I thought it might be an issue with my redux store carrying state between tests. I tried replacing the use of store with a mock store that gets set before each tests like so:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    mockStore = {...store};
});
```

This did not work. With that in mind, the only reason I can see this happening is that react testing library is keeping the same screen state between tests, possibly because they all use the same jsx. If I'm correct, is there a way to clear the screen between each test? If not, what can I do?

Update: I made a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-testing-library-leaky-render-rr34dq?file=/tests/RollGroup.test.tsx) to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the issue was with my redux store. Reusing the same store between tests caused the state to leak into other tests. I solved this by exporting a function `getStore` and calling that whenever I need the store instead of exporting store.